# How to be notified when the user deny fitness data?

Tags: ios, authorization, core-motion

I can check if the user authorized **fitness data** using `-[CMMotionActivityManager queryActivityStartingFromDate:toDate:toQueue:withHandler:]` and check for an error (`CMErrorNotAuthorized` or `CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized`) in the handler.

If the user go to Privacy settings and **deny my app**, the app is killed and when I relaunch it, everything works fine.

If the user go to Privacy settings and **deny fitness data globally**, the app is not killed and the check using the method above does not report any error !

I have to target iOS 8 so I can't use `+[CMSensorRecorder isAuthorizedForRecording]`.

Have you any reliable way of solving this problem ? It is quite *annoying* to have a nice API for location authorization but not for this one!

Comment: When you deny fitness data globally, does the completion handler just return `nil`?

Comment: Nope, it returns the data...Unless I kill the app and relaunch it, in this case it reports the error correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMSensorRecorder_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CMSensorRecorder/isAuthorizedForRecording), + (BOOL)isAuthorizedForRecording is only available on in iOS 9.0 and later, so you can not use it on iOS8.

Comment: Yup, I know I can't use this API :-(